# My Acer aspire x1700 running linux mint 21.1 sometimes freezes up and is slower than Windows 7 was

Tags: linux-mint, cpu, ram, acer

lscpu returns this:

```
    Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:                   36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7300  @ 2.66GHz
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           23
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
Stepping:                        6
CPU max MHz:                     2670.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1603.0000
BogoMIPS:                        5333.32
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 lahf_lm pti dtherm
L1d cache:                       64 KiB (2 instances)
L1i cache:                       64 KiB (2 instances)
L2 cache:                        3 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA node(s):                    1
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion
Vulnerability Mds:               Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Unknown: No mitigations
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Retpolines, STIBP disabled, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
```

Opening programs like hardinfo and gpxviewer cause the computer to freeze up. Any scrolling is slow especially in Firefox. I am using xfce desktop environment. Should I just find another linux distro or is something wrong and how can I fix it? Ubuntu was even slower on it but that was with gnome. Sorry if this is simple but the is my first try at linux. Thanks.